# Excel - De-cumulate data in pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Hope you'll be able to help me.

I have a table with 11 columns, the first one is a date, the next 9 ones are a way of uniquely identifying data and the 11th is a certain amount of money.

What I'm doing in a pivot table is showing the added amount according to one of the identifiers (lines) and dates (columns).

All is well and quite easy to do in a pivot table. Today though I was told that the amounts in my source table are actually cumulative since the beginning of the year.

What I mean is that there are recurring entries in that table and that if I have an entry with the 9 identifiers in january and the same in february and march for example, the value of the one in february is actually (february-january) and for march (march-february).

I could through the unique identifiers just add a column in my source table to identify and calculate the real amount, but I was wondering if there was a way to do so in the pivot table directly ?

Thanks !

Edit :
Here is a screenshot of a simplified version (only two identifiers)
In the fourth column is the amount I have, and in the fifth the real one, that I have to calculate, it is quite easy with only two columns as identifiers.
The goal here is that the pivot table at the bottom shows the "real" amount without me having to create a new column in my source table.
[My example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7CTu.png)

Comment: Can you include some actual data to show what your question is about?  I don't follow what you described above.

Comment: Of course Tim ! I'm sorry if it's not clear, hope the image I've put in my edit will help you (and me :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using *Calculated Item*s. But it is cumbersome.

A *Calculated Item* is just another item that a Pivot Table field can take. It is defined in terms of the other items in the same field. For example, the field `Date` might have values of `Jan17`, `Feb17`, etc. A new calculated item called `Difference` can be added to the `Date` field and defined as `=Feb17-Jan17`. This new `Difference` item will appear whenever the `Date` field is used to provide row or column labels and the values displayed for it in the main body of the pivot table will be equal to the corresponding values for `Feb17` less those for `Jan17`.

The discussion below is based (loosely) on the pivot table in the picture accompanying the question.

Calculated Items cannot be calculated on grouped fields, so it will be necessary to ungroup the `Date` field in the pivot table. This will cause the items in the field to be displayed in the same `dd/mm/yyyy` format as the source data. Changing these to the custom format of `mmmyy` makes them easier to work with. In English (rather than French) they get displayed as `Jan17`, `Feb17`, etc. using this format.

To add a new Calculated Item to the `Date` field, select any item in this field and locate the `Calculated Item` option via the ribbon. This has changed across versions of Excel, in Excel 2010 it is accessed via the "Fields, Items & Sets" button of the "Pivot Table Tools/Options" tab of the ribbon. In later versions it accessed via the "Calculations" button of the same tab. A dialog box will appear as illustrated below.

[image: Inset Calculated Item dialog]

In the Name: box insert a suitable name such as `Feb17X`and in the Formula: box enter `=IF(Feb17=0,0,Feb17-Jan17)`. Click "Add" then "OK". The new `Date` item labelled `Feb17X` will appear in the pivot table and will show values of 20, 0 and 0 against projects A, B and C respectively.

`Feb17X` is the decumulated `Date` item for February. The `IF` is necessary because although the `Amount`values are cumulative, they only appear in the source data whenever a new `Amount` occurs in the month (for example Project B and Department IS has data showing for April and June but not for May).

Similar decumulated `Date` items can be defined in the same way for the other months.

For March, `Mar17X` is defined as
 `=IF(Mar17=0,0,Mar17-(Jan17+Feb17X))` 
and a new `Mar17X` item is added to the `Date` field. Unfortunately, this shows values of -28, 0 and 0 against projects A, B and C, respectively. To get the correct values displayed, it is necessary to add the `Department` field to the row labels in the pivot table (below the `Project` field) and then to use the "Collapse Entire Field" operation to stop the detail of the `Department` field from being visible.

The calculated items for the remaining months are added as expected - that for June is `Jun17X` and has formula
`=IF(Jun17=0,0,Jun17-(Jan17+Feb17X+Mar17X+Apr17X+May17X))`

Once the new items have been defined for the `Date` field, a filter is applied in the pivot table to remove the cumulative items ie, `Feb17`, `Mar17`, `Apr17`, `May17` and `Jun17`. This results in the pivot table displaying the sum of the decumulated values as shown below.

[image: Screenshot]

A few points:

1. The zeroes in the pivot table can be suppressed from display by setting the number format of the `Amount` field to `#`
2. In the larger problem where each `Amount` is defined by a `Date`, `Project` and 8 further field values, the row labels of the pivot table will need to include `Project` and all 8 of the attribute fields. The latter 8 fields will need to be "collapsed out" of the display.
3. It is much, much simpler to add a decumulated `Amount` column to the
   source data range rather than using the Calculated Item approach set
   out here. Sorting the source data by the 9 attributes (`Project`
   first then the remaining 8) and then by `Date` makes the task
   of decumulation very easy. Simply compare the 9 attributes in a row
   with the previous row: if the values are unchanged between the two
   rows, subtract the previous row's `Amount` from the current row's,
   otherwise leave the current row's `Amount` unchanged.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I'm quite good with formulas or even VBA but haven't yet fiddled around with all the possibilities in pivot tables :)
Glad to know there is a way to do it then (even though kinda painful, the project going on for five years) and that it is easier to do it the way I was going to, directly in the source table !